# two class different header, gcc, visual studio 2012

Tags: c++

Why does the compiler give me an error of `Card deck[5]` when the two classes are in different files, but if I put them in the same file the compiler approves?

I did include ".h" to both files.

Header 1

```
class Card  
{
    private:

        char*   card_name;
        int     card_value;
        Color   card_color;

    public:
        Card();

        void    set_card(char * buffer , Card& c);
        Card    get_card(int index,Card deck[]);
        int     get_card_value();
        void    print_card();

        ~Card();
};
```

Header 2

```
class Player
{  


    private:

        friend class Card;
        char*   name;
        char*   id;
        int     wins;
        int     losses;
        int     remains_move;
        struct  Coordinate cord;
        Card    deck[MAX_CARDS];


    public:



        Player();


        int     Player_Array_Size(char* Creation,const int MAX_PLAYERS);
        void    Player_Creation_File(char* Creation);
        void    Player_Simulation_File(char* Simulation,int Array_Size);
        void    set_player();
        Player* get_player();
        void    print_player();
        void    move_to_point(int x ,int y);
        void    attack_using_card(int Attacker ,int Defender,int Attack_card);
        void    win_match();
        void    lose_match();


        ~Player();
```

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. For example when and where and how you include the header files, and more importantly in which order.

Comment: how do you compile your code?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have 4 files, card.h, card.cpp, player.h and player.cpp.
In player.h:

```
#include "card.h"

class Player { ... };
```

In player.cpp:

```
#include "player.h"

...
```

In card.h:

```
class Player; // Forward declaration

class Card { ... };
```

In card.cpp:

```
#include "card.h"
#include "player.h"

...
```

That's it.

Comment: the error is c209 : "plyaer::deck"uses undified claas "card"

Comment: i did it allready :( 
the fact that it work on 1 file of H and C is frustrating
when i spilt it to 2 H and 2 C do include the H file
and i get copmpile errors

Comment: c209 is because you did it wrong. The card header goes into the player header.

Comment: Then could you please mark the question as resolved please? :)